# Can argparse do mutual exclusion of groups instead of just individual options?

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to build an ArgumentParser object with two *groups* of arguments that are mutually exclusive to one another, like so

```
usage: obtain_pizza [-h] --topping TOPPING 
    ( --pizzeria PIZZERIA --budget BUDGET | --check-fridge-only )
```

I attempted to do this by just adding a group inside a mutual exclusion group, like so:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--topping', nargs=1, required=True)

mutually_exclusive_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required = True)

purchase_group = mutually_exclusive_group.add_argument_group('Purchase options')
purchase_group.add_argument('--pizzeria', nargs=1)
purchase_group.add_argument('--budget', nargs=1)

mutually_exclusive_group.add_argument('--check_fridge_only', action='store_true')
```

However this results in the program apparently behaving as though `purchase_group` were at top level:

```
usage: obtain_pizza.py [-h] --topping TOPPING 
       [--pizzeria PIZZERIA] [--budget BUDGET]
       --check_fridge_only
```

(line broken up for readability)

**Note**: I see a similar question at [Set up mutually exclusive sets in argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985474/set-up-mutually-exclusive-sets-in-argparse) but it's nine years old and doesn't have an answer other than using third-party packages.   My question is about doing this using `argparse` specifically.

Comment: There's nothing new.  These groups are not designed for nesting, and hopefully there's nothing in the docs that encourages this.  There has been some discussion about explicitly blocking such attempts.  As an aside, what the `usage` shows and what actually happens in parsing can be different when you push the limits of what's intended.

Comment: As I just commented at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72311036/create-mutual-inclusive-arguments-with-argparse, more complex "interactions" have to be tested for after parsing.  I once worked on generalizing the xor grouping to allow for nesting and other logic, but the change was too big for the default `argparse` module.

Comment: From the docs: "*Changed in version 3.11*: Calling `add_argument_group()` or `add_mutually_exclusive_group()` on a mutually exclusive group is deprecated. These features were never supported and do not always work correctly. The functions exist on the API by accident through inheritance and will be removed in the future."