# Create Mutual Inclusive arguments with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I want to build a program that has 2 mutually inclusive args and 2 that are not dependent on the first two. Something like this:

```
consume [--count n] | show | clear
```

where 'consume' and '--count' are dependent on each other i.e, without 'consume' '--count' will throw an error 'show' and 'clear' do not depend on the first consume and --count.

Edit:
show and clear are optional arguments

Here's what I was able to do till now:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='%(prog)s [consume [--count]]')
group.add_argument('consume', help='mutually inclusive with count')
group.add_argument('--count', type = int, help='get the count n')

parser.add_argument('show', help='show the messages')
parser.add_argument('clear', help='clear messages from db')

args = group.parse_args()
args1 = parser.parse_args()

if args.count and not args.consume:
    parser.error('the following arguments are required: consume')
else:
    print(args.count)
    print(args1.show)
    print(args1.clear)
```

So when the run the command, without consume:

```
[filename] --count 7 show clear
```

I get the following error:

```
unrecognized arguments: clear
```

Can someone help me with making the arguments mutually inclusive and other arguments not dependent on them?

Comment: `argparse` implements 'mutually_exlusive_groups' (flat, not nested), and subcommands.  All other kinds of argument-interactions have to be tested for after parsing.  I know the `argparse` docs are long, but they are reasonably complete.

Comment: @hpaulj Is there no way to implement 'mutually inclusive'?

Comment: Why did you add a second parser? That seems to be causing all your problems. The logic afterwards is probably what you want, although comparisons to `None` should use `is`, so: `if args.count is not None and not args.consume:`. That said, I'm confused why you're using positional arguments as if they're optional arguments or subcommands. Like, should `consume` be changed to `--consume`, etc?

Comment: @Anonymous If `show` and `clear` are optional and positional, how do you expect to tell which one the user is passing

Comment: @Anonymous are any of the arguments positional? or are they all option flags?

Comment: @alexpdev Arguments are positional arguments.

Comment: @Anonymous how can the parser then know which arguments have been given if they are all optional and positional?

Comment: @alexpdev thought about it and tested it. You are right, parser s not able to distinguish between them. Then, should they be option flags?

Comment: @Anonymous that would be my suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this...

Add a `MutuallyInclusiveArgumentError` Exception subclass, then split the arguments in an argument group, and check for errors after parsing has been completed.

```
import argparse
import sys
class MutuallyInclusiveArgumentError(Exception):
    pass

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(sys.argv[0])
subs = parser.add_argument_group("mutually inclusive")
subs.add_argument('--consume', help='mutually inclusive with count', action='store_true')
subs.add_argument('--count', type = int, help='get the count n')
parser.add_argument('--show', help='show the messages', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--clear', help='clear messages from db', action='store_true')


args = parser.parse_args()
if args.count and args.consume is False:
    raise MutuallyInclusiveArgumentError("--count option must be used with the --consume option" )



print(vars(args))
```

the help message looks like this

```
usage: {progname} [-h] [--consume] [--count COUNT] [--show] [--clear]

options:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --show         show the messages
  --clear        clear messages from db

mutually inclusive:
  --consume      mutually inclusive with count
  --count COUNT  get the count n
```

Comment: `consume` isn't supposed to require `--count`, it's supposed to *allow* it.

Comment: `--count` still has `required=True`

Comment: Oh, also, OP just clarified that `show` and `clear` should be optional

Comment: @alexpdev this is the error that I get after running this code: ```unrecognized arguments: show clear``` I run it like: ```[filename] consume --count 5 show clear```

Comment: @anonymous try it now with the optional flags.